# Проблема с компаратором и ТreeSet

Tags: java, коллекции, compare, treeset, comparator

Имеется класс `Human` и производный от него класс `Student`:

```java
public class Human implements Comparable<Human> {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String patronymic;
    private int age;

    public Human(String surname, String name, String patronymic, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getSurname() { return surname; }
    public void setSurname(String surname) { this.surname = surname; }

    public String getPatronymic() { return patronymic; }
    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) { this.patronymic = patronymic; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Human human = (Human) o;
        return age == human.age && Objects.equals(name, human.name) && Objects.equals(surname, human.surname) && Objects.equals(patronymic, human.patronymic);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, surname, patronymic, age);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Human{" +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", patronymic='" + patronymic + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return surname + " " + name + " " + patronymic;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Human o2) {
        return this.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
    }
}
```

```java
//Student
public class Student extends Human {
    String faculty;

    public Student(String surname, String name, String patronymic, int age, String faculty) {
        super(surname, name, patronymic, age);
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    public String getFaculty() { return faculty; }
    public void setFaculty(String faculty) { this.faculty = faculty; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return Objects.equals(faculty, student.faculty);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), faculty);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "faculty='" + faculty + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Мне нужно написать метод, который будет сортировать элементы входного множества объектов, расширяющих `Human` по неубыванию ФИО без явного использования сортировки (задача на изучение JCF).

Я использую `TreeSet` и определяю компаратор внутри метода:

```java
public static List<Human> buildSortedlist(Set<? extends Human> humans) {
    Set<Human> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Human>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Human o1, Human o2) {
            int compareNames = o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
            if (compareNames != 0) {
                return compareNames;
            } else {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
    });
    sortedSet.addAll(humans);
    return new ArrayList<>(sortedSet);
}
```

Однако, если в сете есть люди с полностью одинаковым ФИО, например, "Иванов Иван Иванович 10 лет" и "Иванов Иван Иванович 60 лет", то данный метод оставит в списке только одного из них.

Не понимаю, в чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это общая проблема сортировки с помощью множества: если нужно сортировать одинаковые значения одни должны быть сделаны уникальными/различными. :). Или придётся сменить структуру данных немного.

Comment: Проблема собственно в том, что есть множество с уникальными значениями по одному набору полей, а сортировка выполняется по меньшему набору полей, в котором возникают дубликаты, вследствие чего именно `TreeSet` теряет данные из-за нарушения контракта `compareTo / equals`

Answer (score 1):

Об этом собственно написано в [документации `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): в данной реализации для сравнения элементов используются методы `compareTo` / `compare`, а не стандартная пара методов `hashCode` / `equals` как в обычном множестве (`Set`)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a `set` (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

То есть, для сортированного множества упорядочение должно *соответствовать методу `equals`*, как описано в документации [интерфейса `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> The ordering imposed by a comparator `c` on a set of elements `S` is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `c.compare(e1, e2)==0` has the same `boolean` value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` in `S`.

и [интерфейса `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same `boolean` value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`...

В представленном коде это требование соответствия нарушено, так как *переопределённый* компаратор сначала сравнивает два объекта `Human` по полному имени `o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName())`, и в случае совпадения имён сравнивает объекты при помощи метода `compareTo` из реализации метода `Comparable`, в которой опять же выполняется сравнение только по полному имени, игнорируя другие свойства, которые используются в `hashCode` и `equals` для соответствующих классов (`age` для `Human`, `faculty` для `Student`).

Следовательно, придётся либо переделывать метод `Human::compareTo`, чтобы он учитывал поле `age`, либо переопределять компаратор с той же целью.

Переопределить компаратор можно гораздо лаконичнее с помощью фабричных методов `Сomparator.comparing`, `Сomparator.thenComparing` и др.

```java
public static List<Human> buildSortedlist(Set<? extends Human> humans) {
    Set<Human> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator
        .comparing(Human::getFullName)
        .thenComparing(Human::getAge)
    );
    sortedSet.addAll(humans);
    return new ArrayList<>(sortedSet);
}
```

Правда, и такой вариант не идеален, так как теперь могут теряться экземпляры "студентов" -- полных тёзок и сверстников с разных факультетов, чего можно избежать, "наколхозив" дополнительные сравнения:

```java
public static List<Human> buildSortedlist(Set<? extends Human> humans) {
    Set<Human> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator
        .comparing(Human::getFullName)
        .thenComparing(Human::getAge)
        .thenComparing(h -> h.getClass().getName())
        .thenComparing(h -> ((Student) h).getFaculty())
    );
    sortedSet.addAll(humans);
    return new ArrayList<>(sortedSet);
}
```

Также следует упомянуть о возможном решении данной задачи при помощи Stream API -- фактически, достаточно отсортировать стрим элементов исходного множества и преобразовать его в список:

```java
public static <H extends Human> List<H> buildSortedlist(Set<H> humans) {
    return humans.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(Human::getFullName)
            .thenComparing(Human::getAge)
            .thenComparing(h -> h.getClass().getName())
            .thenComparing(h -> ((Student) h).getFaculty())
        )
        .toList(); // или collect(Collectors.toList()) для Java 8..15
}
```

---

Похожие вопросы на основном SO:

- [Java - `TreeSet` and `hashCode()` - 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470735/)
- [Cannot use comparable with father-son-grandson inheritance - 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694848/)

Comment: Коллекции типа `Human` а компараторы могут работать только со `Student`.

Comment: Использование `Human::getFullName` теряет людей у которых полное имя совпадает, хотя отдельные поля разные.

Comment: Не совсем понял комментарии.  Почему компараторы могут работать только со `Student`?  И как будут совпадать полные имена с разными полями?  Даже в случае пустых полей в полном имени останутся пробелы `"A", "", "" -> "A  "`; `"", "A", "" -> " A "` и т.д.

Comment: В коде компаратора есть приведение к `Student`.

Comment: 1. `" ", "", ""` и `"", " ", ""` приводят к одинаковому `getFullName`. Один объект будет потерян. 2. Если в исходном списке два одинаковых объекта (равных по значению), их всё равно не нужно склеивать. В выходном списке должны оказаться эти два объекта. Я хочу сказать, что мы чиним в принципе не рабочую конструкцию.

Comment: Согласен, что исходная задача выглядит несколько надуманной. Касаемо приведения к `Student` -- я просто в своём тесте использовал сет, в котором были перемешаны экземпляры `Human` и `Student` и в данном случае проверка по факультету будет только для студентов -- остальные компараторы отработают раньше.

Comment: Пустые имена и имена, состоящие из пробелов.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` не подходит потому что он не позволит тёзкам находится вместе в одном контейнере. Вы про это написали в вопросе, я повторяю за вами.

Помещать процедуры упорядочивающие объекты в сами объекты - тупиковый путь. Сложные объекты рано или поздно захочется упорядочивать различными способами. Поэтому метод `compareTo` мало полезен. Иногда у вас один, самый лучший порядок, как у чисел или строк. В сложных объектах самого лучшего порядка нет.

Метод `equals` (и `hashCode`), который сравнивает только ФИО и возраст - нонсенс. Два полных тёзки родившихся в один год - это не один и тот-же человек. Люди не обладают семантикой типа значения. Сложные типы-значения - это вообще редкие звери.

Я удалил из типов `Human` и `Student` все что связано с равенством и порядком. Как тогда сортировать? Через дополнительную структуру `TreeMap`, которая связывает полное имя со списком людей:

```
    private static List<Human> buildSortedlist(Set<? extends Human> humans) {
        TreeMap<String, List<Human>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Human h : humans) {
            String name = h.getFullName();
            if (!map.containsKey(name)) {
                map.put(name, new ArrayList<Human>());
            }
            map.get(name).add(h);
        }
        List<Human> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Human> v : map.values()) {
            list.addAll(v);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Это отлично работает и не требует вносить частный код, связанный с сортировкой, в сам тип. Если вы захотите сортировать людей и студентов по другому, вы напишете другую процедуру, которая по-другому будет вычислять ключи для сравнения и упорядочения объектов. Эти ключи могут быть простыми строками как получилось сейчас или быть сложными объектами, но это будут отдельные объекты, созданные для данного конкретного алгоритма сортировки.

Пример полного кода:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Temp {
    private static class Human {
        protected String surname;
        protected String name;
        protected String patronymic;
        protected int age;

        public Human(String surname, String name, String patronymic, int age) {
            this.surname = surname;
            this.name = name;
            this.patronymic = patronymic;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return surname + " " + name + " " + patronymic;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Human{" +
                "surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", patronymic='" + patronymic + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}'
            ;
        }
    }

    private static class Student extends Human {
        private String faculty;

        public Student(String surname, String name, String patronymic, int age, String faculty) {
            super(surname, name, patronymic, age);
            this.faculty = faculty;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                "surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", patronymic='" + patronymic + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", faculty='" + faculty + '\'' +
                '}'
            ;
        }
    }

    private static List<Human> buildSortedlist(Set<? extends Human> humans) {
        TreeMap<String, List<Human>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Human h : humans) {
            String name = h.getFullName();
            if (!map.containsKey(name)) {
                map.put(name, new ArrayList<Human>());
            }
            map.get(name).add(h);
        }
        List<Human> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Human> v : map.values()) {
            list.addAll(v);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Set<Human> set = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(
            set,
            new Human("a", "b", "c", 20),
            new Student("g", "h", "i", 30, "k"),
            new Human("d", "e", "f", 30)
        );
        for (Human h : set) {
            System.out.println(h);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (Human h : buildSortedlist(set)) {
            System.out.println(h);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java && java Temp
> Human{surname='a', name='b', patronymic='c', age=20}
> Student{surname='g', name='h', patronymic='i', age=30, faculty='k'}
> Human{surname='d', name='e', patronymic='f', age=30}
>
> Human{surname='a', name='b', patronymic='c', age=20}
> Human{surname='d', name='e', patronymic='f', age=30}
> Student{surname='g', name='h', patronymic='i', age=30, faculty='k'}
> ```